# How can I find a value in a row that is not a NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas, null

I know the annual price for four different apples.

Unfortunately, there are years when some apples are missing in price.

I would like to know the unit price for the first year in which the unit price was entered except for the missing year.

The code is as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = {'Price_Y19':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,10],
     'Price_Y20':[np.nan,np.nan,10,9],
     'Price_Y21':[np.nan,10,9,8],
     'Price_Y22':[10,9,8,7]}

index_name = ['yellow apple','red apple','white apple','gray apple']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = a,
                  index = index_name)
df
```

I would like to get below DataFrame

```
b = {'Price_Y19':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,10],
     'Price_Y20':[np.nan,np.nan,10,9],
     'Price_Y21':[np.nan,10,9,8],
     'Price_Y22':[10,9,8,7],
     'Price_Initial':[10,10,10,10],
     'Price_Final':[10,9,8,7],
     'Price_Gap':[0,1,2,3]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = b,
                  index = index_name)
df1
```

I always wait your answer.
Thanks

I don't have any ideas how to make code.

```
df['Price_Initial] = some mehode
```

Answer (score 1):

You can backward or forward filling missing values with select first or last column by position for `Initial/Final` prices, last subtract new columns:

```
df = df.assign(Price_Initial = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0],
               Price_Final = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1],
               Price_Gap = lambda x: x['Price_Initial'].sub(x['Price_Final']))

print (df)
              Price_Y19  Price_Y20  Price_Y21  Price_Y22  Price_Initial  \
yellow apple        NaN        NaN        NaN         10           10.0   
red apple           NaN        NaN       10.0          9           10.0   
white apple         NaN       10.0        9.0          8           10.0   
gray apple         10.0        9.0        8.0          7           10.0   

              Price_Final  Price_Gap  
yellow apple         10.0        0.0  
red apple             9.0        1.0  
white apple           8.0        2.0  
gray apple            7.0        3.0
```

If multiple columns and need filter only `Price_YY` columns:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='Price_Y\d{2}')
df = df.assign(Price_Initial = df1.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0],
               Price_Final = df1.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1],
               Price_Gap = lambda x: x['Price_Initial'].sub(x['Price_Final']))

print (df)
              Price_Y19  Price_Y20  Price_Y21  Price_Y22  Price_Initial  \
yellow apple        NaN        NaN        NaN         10           10.0   
red apple           NaN        NaN       10.0          9           10.0   
white apple         NaN       10.0        9.0          8           10.0   
gray apple         10.0        9.0        8.0          7           10.0   

              Price_Final  Price_Gap  
yellow apple         10.0        0.0  
red apple             9.0        1.0  
white apple           8.0        2.0  
gray apple            7.0        3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`pandas.Series.first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html#pandas-series-first-valid-index) and [`pandas.Series.last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) functions:

```
df['Price_Initial'], df['Price_Final'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x[x.first_valid_index()], x[x.last_valid_index()])).values
df['Price_Gap'] = df['Price_Initial'] - df['Price_Final']
print(df)
```

---

```
              Price_Y19  Price_Y20  Price_Y21  Price_Y22  Price_Initial  \
yellow apple        NaN        NaN        NaN         10           10.0   
red apple           NaN        NaN       10.0          9           10.0   
white apple         NaN       10.0        9.0          8           10.0   
gray apple         10.0        9.0        8.0          7           10.0   

              Price_Final  Price_Gap  
yellow apple         10.0        0.0  
red apple             9.0        1.0  
white apple           8.0        2.0  
gray apple            7.0        3.0
```